# How to refresh laravel template and disable caching?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hey guys i am just playing around with laravel and bascally have the following view:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <style>
            h1 {
                color: #727272;
                font: bold 2em/1.4 verdana;
            }
            .nav-items {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                list-style-type: none;
            }

            .nav-items li {
                display: inline-block;
                margin-right: 10px;
                padding: 1em 1.5em;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                background-color: #eee;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
                box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
                color: #727272;
                text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
<p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->


           <ul class="nav-items">

               @foreach($categories as $category)

                   <li>
                       Category id is {{ $category-> id }} 
                   </li> 

               @endforeach  

            </ul>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Now suppose i change the below code:

```
<ul class="nav-items">

               @foreach($categories as $category)

                   <li>
                       Category id is {{ $category-> id }} 
                   </li> 

               @endforeach  

 </ul>
```

To the following:

```
<ul class="nav-items">

               @foreach($categories as $category)

                   <li>
                       Product id is {{ $category-> id }} // I have only changed the word "Categories" to "Products"
                   </li> 

               @endforeach  

 </ul>
```

I have only changed the word Categories to Products , but when my view loads in the browser i still see the word "Category" instead of "Products" .

The only current solution i have is to change the view file name and than change the view name in the controller, which is quite inconvenient ! , Is there another solution to this problem ? Is this something to do with caching ?

P.S. i have seen a couple of threads on this topic on SO and they did't solve my problem.

Comment: What HTTP server are you using? Because this seems more like a server caching problem, than a Laravel caching problem.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel will compile the template file to a php file to cache it.
You can clear the cache with this command:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: Please check the compiled files if there is the error or not. So we can find out if its a laravel, Server or browser problem.

Comment: what do u mean by that !

Comment: Search for the compiled file in `storage/framework/views`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. 
I was using laragon apache server. 
What I did is I turned off my apache server and started using the php artisan serve command. It seems the apache is responsible for caching my files. :)

Comment: I might have a similar problem. Can you tell me how you detected this?